# image.onError event never fires, but image isn't valid data - need a work around

Tags: javascript, error-handling, mime-types

I am trying to append an image to a page using JavaScript:

```
image = document.createElement('img');
image.onload = function(){
    document.body.appendChild(image);
}
image.onerror = function(){
    //display error
}
image.src = 'http://example.com/image.png';
```

The user must be authenticated to see this image, and if they are not, I want to display an error message. Unfortunately, the server is not returning an HTTP error message, but rather redirect the request to a (mostly) empty page, so I am getting an `HTTP 200`, but the warning `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html` and nothing is displaying.

How can I handle this case? I don't have the ability to change what the webserver serves up if the user isn't authenticated.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In the `image.onload` event listener, check whether `image.width` and `image.height` are both zero (preferably `image.naturalWidth` and `image.naturalHeight`, when they are supported).

If the width and height are both zero, the image is considered invalid.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RbNeG/

```
// Usage:
loadImage('notexist.png');

function loadImage(src) {
    var image = new Image;
    image.onload = function() {
        if ('naturalHeight' in this) {
            if (this.naturalHeight + this.naturalWidth === 0) {
                this.onerror();
                return;
            }
        } else if (this.width + this.height == 0) {
            this.onerror();
            return;
        }
        // At this point, there's no error.
        document.body.appendChild(image);
    };
    image.onerror = function() {
        //display error
        document.body.appendChild(
            document.createTextNode('\nError loading as image: ' + this.src)
        );
    };
    image.src = src;
}
```

Comment: PS. `document.appendChild` is an invalid call. `document` is not a node, so you cannot append an element to it. To insert the image in the document, use `document.body.appendChild`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm actually doing, just left it out in this by accident. :)

Comment: FYI: These checks fail in Internet Explorer for SVG graphics, because all the values you are checking are `0`. :-(

Comment: Given the date of this question, I'd still resort to `onerror`, see: https://javascript.info/onload-onerror#other-resources.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. If I've 404 for my image - I try to insert one of my array that is 200 OK (Pure Javascript). Images must be in same path. Otherwise - my func will return 'no-image.png'.
[jQuery/JavaScript to replace broken images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images/43281517#43281517)