# How to show alternate image if background-image is not found

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

Here is the fiddle-
http://jsfiddle.net/gfWES/59/

When background-image will point to the location where it would not find a image, I want to show an alternate image which is located at below location-
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg

Ultimately, I have to achieve the above in knockout.

```
<td class="cell">
<div class="contact-photo" data-bind="click: $parent.onAlertClick, style: { backgroundImage:     $parent.photoUrl($data) }, css: { 'has-notifications': $parent.showAlert($data)}, onerror:alert('error')"></div>
</td>
```

In above code- if "$parent.photoUrl($data)" points to a url where image doesn't exist, I want to point "backgroundImage:" to some other location to show any alternate image.

Answer (score 1):

The only way of checking if an image exists is to *request* it.
Using jQuery you'd do a `$.ajax({url:'somefile.png', type:'HEAD', error:image_does_not_exist});`
where `image_does_not_exist` is a callback function. Then you'd set the value returned by `photoUrl` to the default one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.!!                                                                 But, what if it turns out to be a cross browser request which is not allowed straight away.

Comment: Then it's not possible. You need proper CORS headers on the response. _But_ a good alternative (that does not require CORS) is to use an `img` and listen to `onLoad` on it as described in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809015/image-onerror-event-never-fires-but-image-isnt-valid-data-need-a-work-around