# jQuery how to check if uploaded file is an image without checking extensions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Newbie here. The problem is that I currently have written a method which checks uploaded file size and extension in order to validate it. However, checking extensions is not a solution as that kind of validation may cause a lot of problems. What I want to do is to check the actual file type and validate it without using extension method. I have tried to use [jQuery file validator](http://adamsanderson.github.io/jQuery-File-Validator/) but to no avail... This is a snippet from my current code:

```
<input type='file' id='imageLoader' name='imageLoader' accept="image/*" data-type='image' />
```

Script:

```
App.Dispatcher.on("uploadpic", function() {         
        $(":file").change(function() {
            if (this.files && this.files[0] && this.files[0].name.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/) ) {
                if(this.files[0].size>1048576) {
                    alert('File size is larger than 1MB!');
                }
                else {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                }
            } else alert('This is not an image file!');
        });
        function imageIsLoaded(e) {
            result = e.target.result;
            $('#image').attr('src', result);
        };
    });
```

It is called once the upload input changes and after validation it uploads and displays the image. For now, I only care about validation and any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try something like this:

**JavaScript**

```
const file = this.files[0];
const  fileType = file['type'];
const validImageTypes = ['image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png'];
if (!validImageTypes.includes(fileType)) {
    // invalid file type code goes here.
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var file = this.files[0];
var fileType = file["type"];
var validImageTypes = ["image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png"];
if ($.inArray(fileType, validImageTypes) < 0) {
     // invalid file type code goes here.
}
```

Comment: God, why I haven't thought about this? So simple, yet works perefectly, thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't use capital letters to start a variable's name in Javascript.

Comment: When I tried the same for docx extension files then file type is empty. Can you tell why it is and how I can check this ?

Comment: @Varinder may be you can post a question on what you tried? This should be able to work with Microsoft Word documents as well.

Comment: Don't forget image/svg+xml

Comment: This answer isn't right. If you change the extension of a file to, for example, .png or .jpg, you will always get a valid image file, even if your file is a pdf, txt or something not related with an image. Check @sujit answer or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222786/file-upload-check-if-valid-image) for a valid solution

Comment: In the documentation it is at bold this: "Developers are advised not to rely on this property as a sole validation scheme." https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/File/type#Example.

Answer (score 42):

You don't need jquery here.

```
var mimeType=this.files[0]['type'];//mimeType=image/jpeg or application/pdf etc...


//ie image/jpeg will be ['image','jpeg'] and we keep the first value
    if(mimeType.split('/')[0] === 'image'){
       console.log('the file is image');
    }
```

You can also create a function to check when a file is image.

```
function isImage(file){
   return file['type'].split('/')[0]=='image');//returns true or false
}

 isImage(this.file[0]);
```

**Update** (es6)

using es6 `includes` method, makes it even more simple.

```
const isImage = (file) => file['type'].includes('image');
```

Answer (score 11):

Pls refer a related query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809015/image-onerror-event-never-fires-but-image-isnt-valid-data-need-a-work-around). The answer here suggests to load the image in an Image object and check for it's width and height properties to be non zero.
I think the technique can be used to solve your problem too.

I also worked out a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sujitkm/qLmL3vqj) for you to refer. Pertinent code below:

```
var img = new Image();
img.addEventListener("load",function(){
  alert('success');
});
img.addEventListener("error",function(){
      alert('error');
});
  img.src = picFile.result;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Other answers user `file.type`, that only have the information of the file extension. For more information check https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/File/type#Example

Answer (score 7):

Here is a quick tip if you just want to know if the file is an image:

```
var file = this.files[0];
var fileType = file["type"];

if (fileType.search('image') >= 0) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> What I want to do is to check the actual file type

Try accessing `files[0].type` property . See [Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)

```js
$(":file").on("change", function(e) {

  console.log(this.files[0].type);
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='file' id='imageLoader' name='imageLoader' accept="image/*" data-type='image' />
```

Comment: Somehow I managed to miss this .type thingy, no sophisticated methods are needed, this works great, thank you (:

Comment: Just curious. As per your original question "However, checking extensions is not a solution as that kind of validation may cause a lot of problems. What I want to do is to check the actual file type": - Want to check whether the type attribute really returns anything other than checking the extension internally. Since, while I was attempting to answer the OP, i found that when i renamed a text file to a.png and uploaded it, the type attribute check for image was a success even though the actual file wasn't one.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of convoluted answers here.
Simply check whether the file has an image mime-type (which would be of the format `image/...`

```js
const isImage = file => file.type.startsWith("image/")
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone comes here who is using jQuery Validator, a simple method would be:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    "onlyimages",
    function (value, element) {
        if (this.optional(element) || !element.files || !element.files[0]) {
            return true;
        } else {
            var fileType = element.files[0].type;
            var isImage = /^(image)\//i.test(fileType);
            return isImage;
        }
    },
    'Sorry, we can only accept image files.'
);
```

which is then added to the .validate() function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#direct_upload').change(function() {

      if (this.files[0].type.includes('image')) {
        document.getElementById('attach_file').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])
      } else {
        console.log('it is a doc');
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert file type in string and after that slice this string like that:

```
if(String(file.type).slice(0, 6) === 'image/') {....some code}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery version 3.3.1:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Select Image</label>
  <br>
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
</body>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("change", ".custom-file-input", function() {
      var myImg = this.files[0];
      var myImgType = myImg["type"];
      var validImgTypes = ["image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png"];

      if ($.inArray(myImgType, validImgTypes) < 0) {
        alert("Not an image")
      } else {
        alert("Is an image")
      }

    });
  });
</script>

</html>
```