# file upload: check if valid image

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I want to upload a file like this:

```
<input type="file" name="uploadPicture"/>
```

Is there any way to find out in javascript if the selected file is a valid image?

I know that I can check the file extension. The problem with that is someone can change a `.txt` file to `.jpg` and it would pass the validation.

Comment: How are you going to upload it? Maybe you can check it server side? Or you could load the image into the HTML File API and check the mime type.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Firstly add `accept="image/*"` on your input, to accept only image files

```
<input type="file" name="uploadPicture" accept="image/*" onChange="validateAndUpload(this);"/>
```

Second, you can create image object to see if it is true image

```
function validateAndUpload(input){
    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var file = input.files[0];

    if (file) {
        var image = new Image();

        image.onload = function() {
            if (this.width) {
                 console.log('Image has width, I think it is real image');
                 //TODO: upload to backend
            }
        };

        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
};​
```

Comment: What about non jQuery?

Comment: this doesn't work. you also need to subscribe to the onerror event. onload will only be called if the image is valid.

Comment: inventive answer!

Answer (score 28):

Thank you, [Arūnas Smaliukas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32223032/266531). Your answer got me close to what I wanted.

`Image.onload` will only be called if the file is a valid image. So, it's not necessary to inspect `this.width` in the `onload()` call back.

To detect that it is an invalid image, you can use `Image.onerror`.

```js
$().ready(function() {
  $('[type="file"]').change(function() {
    var fileInput = $(this);
    if (fileInput.length && fileInput[0].files && fileInput[0].files.length) {
      var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      var image = new Image();
      image.onload = function() {
        alert('Valid Image');
      };
      image.onerror = function() {
        alert('Invalid image');
      };
      image.src = url.createObjectURL(fileInput[0].files[0]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" />
```

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: Remember to use URL.revokeObjectURL(image.src) to free up the memory used by this ObjectURL once it's no longer needed.

Comment: is there anything in dropzone that does this? I'm using AWS to store files, so I have to override dropzone's icon-drawing to load an amazon-lambda-generated thumbnail image. But I would still like to verify the image works before uploading to S3, triggering lambda and waiting for the result.

Answer (score 2):

In order to check the image file type on client side, you can go for this:

```js
function imageChange(e) {

    if (e.target.files[0].type.split("/")[0] === "image") {

      //code

    } else {

      //code

    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Except for adding `accept="image/*"` to the input check the file type property:

`imageFile.type.includes('image');`

or for very old browsers:

`imageFile.type.match(/image/);`

To get the file itself that `imageFile` is referencing add an event listener to the input. On `change` get the file with `event.currentTarget.files[0]`;