# How to detect if a file input is populated in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

**What I'm using**

- Angular
- Firebase

**What I'm trying to achieve**

- When uploading project details I want to know whether an image has been selected or not.
- If not, call a different method from the service and assign a default image
- If so, use image

**Questions**

I may be approaching this wrong, but the way I was thinking of performing this logic was to see if the user has selected 'select image' (input of type file). If an image has been selected, the 'if (file)' seems to register fine, if an image hasn't been selected it errors out with the following:

> ProjectsAddComponent.html:71 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined

1. How can I detect if the user has chosen an image to upload with the data?

**Project Add HTML**

```html
<div class="vs__upload__container">
  <input type="file" id="file-1" class="inputfile inputfile-1" (change)="detectFiles($event)" />
  <label class="vs__upload__button" for="file-1">
    <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span>Choose a file&hellip;</span>
  </label>
</div>


<div class="vs__details__actions">
  <button class="vs__button"  (click)="addNewProject(newTitle.value, newReference.value, newDate.value); newTitle.value=''; 
  newReference.value=''; newDate.value='';"> 
  Add 
  </button>
</div>
```

**Project Add Component TS**

Please refer to the 'addNewProject' function if statement

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProjectsAddService } from './projects-add.service';
import { Upload } from './upload';
import * as _ from "lodash";

@Component({
  selector: 'upload-form',
  templateUrl: './projects-add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects-add.component.css']
})
export class ProjectsAddComponent {

  selectedFiles: FileList;
  currentUpload: Upload;

  constructor(private upSvc: ProjectsAddService) { }

  detectFiles(event) {
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
  }

  uploadSingle() {
    let file = this.selectedFiles.item(0)
    this.currentUpload = new Upload(file);
  }

  addNewProject(title: string, reference: string, date: string) {
    let file = this.selectedFiles.item(0)
    this.currentUpload = new Upload(file);
    if (file) {
      console.log('this is the file = ', file);
      // Call method in service to include the upload file
this.upSvc.addNewProjectWithImage(title, reference, date, this.currentUpload);
    } else {
      console.log('no file');
      this.upSvc.addNewProjectWithOutImage(title, reference, date);
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: html code for your file upload ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've added it now :)

Comment: the code seems to be correct, all you want to know is if the uploaded file is an image or some other file? Or did I understand the question wrong?

Comment: Hi Faisal. I have a 'form' if you will that has five or so input fields. It also has an additional input field to upload an image. However, if the user has decided not to select an image, when they click 'add', I want to call a certain method. If they have decided to select an image, i want to call a different method. The if statement I have is incorrect for when there isn't an image. If one has been selected it registers fine. However, if there isn't one selected it errors out.

Comment: @MegaTron take a look at this answer, maybe it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/34073139/4222181

Comment: I'm hoping it's something on the if statement. As mentioned above 'if (file)' seems to work. It's when there isn't a 'file' that it errors out. It's in the 'else' part of the statement where I would call a different function.

Comment: i understand your problem, please see the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if any files have been selected. Your code is probably throwing undefined exception.

```
addNewProject(title: string, reference: string, date: string) 
{        
    // Check if an image file has been selected
    if(this.selectedFiles && this.selectedFiles.length > 0) {
       let file = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
       this.currentUpload = new Upload(file);
       console.log('this is the file = ', file);
       // Call method in service to include the upload file
       this.upSvc.addNewProjectWithImage(title, reference, date, this.currentUpload);
    } 
    // otherwise call the method with default image.
    else {
       console.log('no file');
       this.upSvc.addNewProjectWithOutImage(title, reference, date);
    }
}
```

Check the same condition in your `uploadSingle` method.

```
uploadSingle() { 
    if(this.selectedFiles && this.selectedFiles.length > 0) { 
        let file = this.selectedFiles.item(0); 
        this.currentUpload = new Upload(file); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude! - This looks like it can work. I just need to hook everything else up. Thanks alot! Much appreciated.