# file input used for both images and files

Tags: javascript, html

Need help brainstorming.
I have a web page where I am submitting files to a folder on my server. Everything works, but I didn't consider that images taken from a phone are much larger than screen shots or other files. 
I found this post where I can use canvas to resize my images, and send those to the server. This works. However in some cases people might be submitting both images and files like pdfs or docxs. 
I currently find all images in the input type="file" resize them and send them away, so all non images are not being submitted.

I've tried googling how to do this without submitting the images twice, since the file list still has the unaltered images + files. 
I've thought of making two separate input type files, one for image and one for files, but that might be a little too much for the person using it. 
I was just wondering how I could do this?
any idea or thought would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the file extension before

```
$isImage = array('gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg');
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (in_array($ext, $isImage)) {
    echo 'file is image';
        // resize code
}else {
    echo 'file is not an image';
}
```

Comment: Checking the extension is far from being enough. If you want to necessarily check if a file is an img directly in the browser, [this approach is neat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222786/file-upload-check-if-valid-image) (look at the script and not the tag)