# Resolve promise when all images are loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I was preloading images with the following code:

```
    function preLoad() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var imageArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.abbreviations.length; i++) {
            imageArray[i] = new Image();
            imageArray[i].src = $scope.abbreviations[i].imgPath;
        }
        imageArray.forEach.onload = function () {
            deferred.resolve();
            console.log('Resolved');
        }
        imageArray.forEach.onerror = function () {
            deferred.reject();
            console.log('Rejected')
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    preLoad();
```

I thought images were all loading correctly because I could see the 'Resolved' log.

Later somebody pointed out that the code above doesn't guarantee that all images are loaded before resolving the promise. In fact, only the first promise is resolved.

I was advised to use `$q.all` applied to an array of promises instead.
This is the resulting code:

```
    function preLoad() {
        var imageArray = [];
        var promises;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.abbreviations.length; i++) {
            imageArray[i] = new Image();
            imageArray[i].src = $scope.abbreviations[i].imgPath;
        };

        function resolvePromises(n) {
            return $q.when(n);
        }
        promises = imageArray.map(resolvePromises);
        $q.all(promises).then(function (results) {
            console.log('array promises resolved with', results);
        });
    }
    preLoad();
```

This works, but I want to understand:

1. what's happening in each function;
2. why I need `$q.all` to make sure all images are loaded before resolving the promises.

The [relevant docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) are somewhat cryptic.

Comment: Where did you get this `imageArray.forEach.onload` from?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos do you mean it should be `imageArray.onload` instead?

Comment: I wonder why you're talking of the "first promise"… there is only one promise in your first snippet.

Comment: I don't think your second code works. Yes, it does log the finial message, but it does log it too early. Nowhere in this code you are awaiting `load` or `error` events, and I'm pretty confident that `$q.when` does not automagically do this when being passed an `Image`.

Comment: @Ursus neither this would work.

Comment: This may only be working now because you have cached images in your browser. You need promises and a load handler for each image to make it work properly

Comment: @charlietfl fair point. I did try a hard reload and empty cache in Chrome and as far as I can tell (by looking at the network tab) the images are loaded

Comment: can also do it the old fashioned way without promises and using a counter and update count in onload

Comment: @Bergi and charlietfl any suggestion in an answer would be helpful, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dtg7OVgz4crk3KRmYT3v?p=preview).

Your function:

```
function preLoad() {

    var promises = [];

    function loadImage(src) {
        return $q(function(resolve,reject) {
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = src;
            image.onload = function() {
              console.log("loaded image: "+src);
              resolve(image);
            };
            image.onerror = function(e) {
              reject(e);
            };
        })
    }

    $scope.images.forEach(function(src) {
      promises.push(loadImage(src));
    })

    return $q.all(promises).then(function(results) {
        console.log('promises array all resolved');
        $scope.results = results;
        return results;
    });
}
```

The idea is very similar to Henrique's answer, but the onload handler is used to resolve each promise, and onerror is used to reject each promise.

To answer your questions:

1) Promise factory

```
$q(function(resolve,reject) { ... })
```

constructs a Promise. Whatever is passed to the `resolve` function will be used in the `then` function. For example:

```
$q(function(resolve,reject) {
     if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) > 4) {
         resolve("success")
     }
     else {
         reject("failure")
     }
}.then(function wasResolved(result) {
    console.log(result) // "success"
}, function wasRejected(error) {
    console.log(error) // "failure"
})
```

2) $q.all is passed an array of promises, `then` takes a function which is passed an array with the resolutions of all the original promises.

Comment: I don't see the difference. What do you mean by "*but the onload handler is used to resolve each promise, and onerror is used to reject each promise.*"? Btw, you should post your code, especially the `loadImage` function, in your answer, not on some plunker.

Comment: Nice, you're right & it's edited. To answer your question, instead of determining to resolve/reject in the onload handler, I trust the onerror handler to decide whether to reject. The onload handler can only resolve. Depends on the use case, but the other solution could be better if you need more granular rejection criteria. Also, i wanted to actually explain promises a little more in depth to OP

Comment: Ah, right. Notice that Henrique had to fix this as well, see the comments on his answer for details :-)

Comment: @ShaharZ thanks for the effort. At first blush, your snippet looks clearer than Henrique's. I'll also give it a go. +1.

Comment: @ShaharZ in your link function `console.log(newVal,oldVal);` returns `undefined, undefined`.

Comment: @ShaharZ also why are you injecting `function($scope,$q)` inside the controller in the plnkr? You're already injecting `$scope` and `$q`...

Comment: @ShaharZ although my final solution is slightly different, your answer helped me a lot, thanks.

Comment: $scope.$watch('results') will fire when the $scope.results first initializes, so at that point it is 'undefined'. If you use dependency injection, you must put the controller function in the injection array! The order of arguments matters.

Comment: @U r s u s Also important, this directive in the plunkr works because it is on the same scope as controller and relies on a scope var named "results". If we wanted to use an arbitrary scope variable, we would pass it in directive HTML attribute, and use an isolate scope in the directive definition.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not used to angular promise library, but the idea is as follows:

```
function getImagePromise(imgData) {
    var imgEl = new Image();
    imgEl.src = imgData.imgPath;

    return $q(function(resolve, reject){
        imgEl.addEventListener('load', function(){
            if ((
                   'naturalHeight' in this 
                    && this.naturalHeight + this.naturalWidth === 0
                ) 
                || (this.width + this.height == 0)) {
                reject(new Error('Image not loaded:' + this.src));
            } else {
                resolve(this);
            }
        });

        imgEl.addEventListener('error', function(){
            reject(new Error('Image not loaded:' + this.src));
        });
    })
}

function preLoad() {
    return $q.all($scope.abbreviations.map(getImagePromise));
}

// using
preLoad().then(function(data){
    console.log("Loaded successfully");
    data.map(console.log, console);
}, function(reason){
    console.error("Error loading: " + reason);
});
```

Comment: Did you leave out adding an `onerror` handler on purpose?

Comment: Did you mean `onerror` handler for the `Image` element?

Comment: Yes, exactly. OP had used one so I wondered whether your test for the dimensions in the `onload` handler is known to be sufficient?

Comment: `onerror` will be triggered only when the response status is different from `200`. The approach I used on the post is bullet-proof for cases where a `200` status can be returned, but the response content (mime) is not an image. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809015/image-onerror-event-never-fires-but-image-isnt-valid-data-need-a-work-around) is related.

Comment: But nothing prevents OP from using it instead if he thinks he will never face this sort of problem.

Comment: Yes, but afaik (and how I understood [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#update-the-image-data)) no `load` event is fired when *no* 200 status is returned - there are cases where only `error` is fired.

Comment: You are right, so a robust solution have to include both approaches. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos I'll test this and get back to you. +1 for now :) Quick question: what's the 'natural height' thing about?